# golang binary not working outside gopath src folder

Tags: go

I have a golang web application defined using gin-gonic. I have defined the the goapp under /usr/local/goapp
The structure is like this -
 /usr/local/goapp
                 +src
                 +bin
                 +pkg
Here are my go env -
GOPATH - /usr/local
GOBIN - /usr/local/goapp/bin
GOROOT - /usr/local/go

When I run go build and go install under the main folder in source, I get my binary and I am able to run it and see my html getting loaded when I go to the home page URL.
If I try to run the same binary under bin folder, I don't see the html getting loaded when I go to the home page URL. I am getting 404 page not found.

Am I missing something here? Has anyone came across such a kind of issue?

Thanks.

Comment: There is no need to set GOROOT.

Comment: Most probably cause of this problem: Your code accesses files (e.g. templates) via a relative path. This has nothing to do with GOPATH, GOBIN or whatever, it is just a missunderstanding how file access works.

Comment: Thanks. I moved my static files to the same location as the binary and it fixed the issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All those GOPATH, GOROOT and of course the missing PATH variables just say something about how to call the go program itself and where it searches for modules. But you told us, that you built and installed some go program.

When a go program has been built go is actually not needed anymore. You can take the binary, put it anywhere you want, even to another machine, that has the same or at least a similar system and run that program there.

When your program, that you have built and installed and that seems to be called gin-gonic is executed, you will execute it in some path, also known as the current working directory (see getcwd(2) or pwd(1)).

I just guess now, that under the current working directory there lives your htdocs, index.html, whatever files, that this gin-gonic uses to create the pages.

It is common, that, if such a program cannot find the document it should create, send, produce, whatever, it will return the code 404: Not found.

Though just guessed, this is, quite likely, the situation you are in, when you run your program with a different current working directory, than the working directory, under which the program expects its documents.

Comment: Thanks guys. That was the issue. The static html and javascript files were not in the current working directory. Is there a good library to package all the static contents with in the same binary?

Comment: The most common and simple approach is to change the working directory, possibly based on a command line option, when the server starts. I don't know what you mean with "package". I use `tar` for such purpose.